# Alternate between 3 colors in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-color

I have a UITableView that I would like to display in 3 different background colors. Basically white, light gray, dark gray, then back to white and so on.

This is all I have been able to find on stack overflow so far:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    } else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

This works perfect for 2 colors. How can I alternate between 3 colors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `3` instead of `2` and then set the values accordingly, e.g.:

```
NSInteger colorIndex = indexPath.row % 3;

switch (colorIndex) {
    case 0:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        break;
}
```

You can also use `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]` with whatever numeric values you want if you want a more shades of gray (e.g. 50).

Comment: Worked like a charm and you were the first to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Rob` is correct but i will use `default color` provided by `UIColor`:

```
NSInteger colorIndex = indexPath.row % 3;

switch (colorIndex) {
    case 0:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    if(indexPath.row % 3 ==0){
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
    if((indexPath.row-1) % 3 ==0){
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

    if((indexPath.row - 2) % 3 ==0){
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```